# stop panning to my location after camera update

Tags: android, google-maps, location

I have set up a map with points marked on it which works fine.  I open a map and move and zoom to my location.  The problem is that when I pan from my location, after a moment it takes me back to my location.  How do you move and zoom and then release the move at my location.

Here is the code to move and zoom:

```
private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
    if (mMap == null) {
        // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();

        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
        if (mMap != null) {
            setUpMap();

            mMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onMyLocationChange(Location arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    LatLng myLocation =  new LatLng(arg0.getLatitude(),
                            arg0.getLongitude());
                    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
                    CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(myLocation, 11);
                    mMap.moveCamera(update);
                    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .position(myLocation)
                            .title("Brian is Here!"));

                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I think it is easy but I cannot find the answer.

Any Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can "easily" solve, if you want to go to your location at every change, the code is correct, if you don't want, the problem is in the camera change when the location changes.

You can do it only once by just set the location listener as you did, and then at the end of the animation remove the listener. This will run the animation the first time, and then, since listener is removed, will avoid to again move to the location.

Comment: @N Dorigatti  Thanks that will work.  Thought it would be easy, Just this is my first android app.